# Conditionally writing data to firebase real time database by changing firebase database rules

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to compare the existing barcode data set in Realtime Database when I add new data. If only these barcode value exists, this incoming data should be written in Realtime Database. If it is not, new data should not be written. Can I do it by changing Firebase rules?

Rules I tried have been added below but it didn't work.

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Smart_Cart_Products": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "newData.child(\"barcode\").val() == data.child(\"barcode\").val()"   
    }
  } 
}
```

Json data

```
"Smart_Cart_Products": [
    {
      "Desc1": "234",
      "Desc2": "248",
      "Desc3": "0.00",
      "barcode": "1674026293"
    },
    {
      "Desc1": "235",
      "Desc2": "249",
      "Desc3": "0.01",
      "barcode": "1674026293"
    },
    {
      "Desc1": "236",
      "Desc2": "250",
      "Desc3": "0.02",
      "barcode": "1674026293"
    },
    {
      "Desc1": "237",
      "Desc2": "251",
      "Desc3": "0.03",
      "barcode": "1674026293"
    },
    {
      "Desc1": "238",
      "Desc2": "252",
      "Desc3": "0.04",
      "barcode": "1674026293"
    }
"Barcodes": [
    {
      "barcode": "1674026297"
     },
    {
      "barcode": "1674026296"
     },
    {
      "barcode": "1674026294"
     },
    {
      "barcode": "1674026293"
    },
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data refer this one, i supposed you will get a idea.

Comment: What doesn't work about the rules you shared? Can you share a code sample? Is there an error message?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that [Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) and should not be used as such. There's a great answer by @FrankvanPuffelen but I think the bigger question is; why don't you simply query to see if the barcode exists and if so, write the data? No rules are needed for that at all.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you only want the user to be able to write a node under `/Smart_Cart_Products` if the `barcode` value they specify exists under `/Barcodes` already.

With your current structure that is not possible as security rules can't search data (as that wouldn't scale). To allow the use-case, you'll want to change the `/Barcodes` structure to:

```
"Barcodes": {
  "1674026297": true,
  "1674026296": true,
  "1674026294": true,
  "1674026293": true
},
```

Now with this, you can control the writes to `/Smart_Cart_Products` with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Smart_Cart_Products": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "root.child('Barcodes').child(newData.child('barcode').val()).exists()"   
    }
  } 
}
```

So with the new data structure, this rule can now check whether the barcode the write specifies exists under `/Barcodes`.